# How to send array to HttpPost from Angular to .Net Framework(ApiController)?

Tags: asp.net, .net, angular, typescript, web-services

I trying to send Angular array data to .Net Framework server side

My current code looks like:

*Angular:* code below

service.ts

```
   addRecipient(val:any)
    {
      return this.http.post(this.APIUrl+'/recipient',val);
    }
```

recipient.ts

`SendSurveyList: any = [];` - **declared list**

`this.SendSurveyList.push(val);` **- pushing results**

**Sending results via server:** ->

```
  this.service.addRecipient(this.SendSurveyList).subscribe(res=>
        {
          alert(res.toString() + "Was Sent");
        });
```

*.Net Framework:* code below

```
 // POST api/values
        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]Recipient postRecipient)
        {
        }
```

1. Current Result: HttpPost returning null;
2. Expecting result: HttPost returning SendSurveyList list data.

My idea:

I have an idea to change service.ts side post url to like:

```
 addRecipient():Observable<any[]>
    {
      return this.http.post(this.APIUrl+'/recipients');
    }
```

But this is valid only for http.GET side ~ I don't actually know how to realize it from http.Post.

> I am also looking forward to your ideas. Since I managed to implement
> Post for a single record. But I would like to do it for List / Array
> data throug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// POST api/values
        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]List<Recipient> listPostRecipient)
        {
        }
```